# Downloading files from a site with javascript links

Tags: javascript, html

I sometimes find sites that post content (files) as javascript links. In cases where the links are posted with the traditional `<a href="...">` construct, one can easily parse the HTML, find the link and download the content. Even applications like Acrobat are able to handle this and generate a PDF of the relevant area of a site.

Not so with javascript links.

Here is an example of a site which has content (public access, no login or password required) but uses javascript links.

How does one go about downloading the PDF files here programmatically?

http://www.oml.ago.state.ma.us/

There are tabs for each year, take this one for 2013.

http://www.oml.ago.state.ma.us/Default.aspx?sectionYear=1&year=2013

There are several hundred links here but short of clicking on each one I can't figure any way of finding the target and downloading them.

Comment: @Leonid, I didn't have a particular language in mind. I was hoping it would be a shell script but if it means programming it in some language then I'd assume that java would be option #1. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

Two options spring to mind (neither of them Java):

1. Write a JavaScript bookmarklet that you can click on in your browser and scrape the DOM elements *after* the page you want to scrape has loaded and the JS has executed. This will work but won't scale for a large number of pages.
2. Use a headless browser like http://casperjs.org/, http://phantomjs.org/ or http://slimerjs.org/

Answer (score 0):

You can find it with a developer console, looking at the network.

The url is `http://www.oml.ago.state.ma.us/default.aspx`, with some post parameters :

```
Host: www.oml.ago.state.ma.us
User-Agent: [...]
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: fr,fr-fr;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
DNT: 1
Referer: http://www.oml.ago.state.ma.us/
Cookie: [...]
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 5713

__EVENTTARGET=ctl00%24ContentPlaceHolder1%24grdOML%24ctl02%24lnkOpenFile&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__VIEWSTATE=%2FwEPDwUKLTI3MjY2NDEzNg9kFgJmD2QWAgIDD2QWAgIBD2QWCAIBD2QWAmYPFgIeBFRleHQFgQM8dGFibGUgd2lkdGg9JzcwJScgY2VsbHBhZGRpbmc9JzInIGNlbGxzcGFjaW5nPScyJyBib3JkZXI9JzAnPjx0cj48dGQgYmdjb2xvcj0nI2RjZGNkMCdhbGlnbj0nbGVmdCcgdmFsaWduPSdtaWRkbGUnY2xhc3M9J25hdmlnYXRpb25UZXh0J3dpZHRoPSc0MCUnPjxiPjxhIGhyZWY9J0RlZmF1bHQuYXNweD9zZWN0aW9uPTAnPkJyb3dzZSBPTUwgRGV0ZXJtaW5hdGlvbnM8L2E%2BPC9iPjwvdGQ%2BPHRkIGJnY29sb3I9JyNmMGYwZTgnYWxpZ249J2xlZnQnIHZhbGlnbj0nbWlkZGxlJ2NsYXNzPSduYXZpZ2F0aW9uVGV4dCd3aWR0aD0nMzUlJz48YSBocmVmPSdTZWFyY2guYXNweD9zZWN0aW9uPTEnPlNlYXJjaCBPTUwgRGV0ZXJtaW5hdGlvbnM8L2E%2BPC90ZD48L3RyPjwvdGFibGU%2BZAIDD2QWAmYPFgIfAAWbBjx0YWJsZSB3aWR0aD0nMTAwJScgY2VsbHBhZGRpbmc9JzInIGNlbGxzcGFjaW5nPScyJyBib3JkZXI9JzAnPjx0cj48dGQgYmdjb2xvcj0nI2RjZGNkMCdhbGlnbj0nbGVmdCcgdmFsaWduPSd0b3AnY2xhc3M9J25hdmlnYXRpb25UZXh0J3dpZHRoPScyMiUnPjxiPjxhIGhyZWY9J0RlZmF1bHQuYXNweD9zZWN0aW9uWWVhcj0wJnllYXI9MjAxNCc%2BMjAxNDwvYT48L2I%2BPC90ZD48dGQgYmdjb2xvcj0nI2YwZjBlOCdhbGlnbj0nbGVmdCcgdmFsaWduPSd0b3AnY2xhc3M9J25hdmlnYXRpb25UZXh0J3dpZHRoPScxOS41JSc%2BPGEgaHJlZj0nRGVmYXVsdC5hc3B4P3NlY3Rpb25ZZWFyPTEmeWVhcj0yMDEzJz4yMDEzPC9hPjwvdGQ%2BPHRkIGJnY29sb3I9JyNmMGYwZTgnYWxpZ249J2xlZnQnIHZhbGlnbj0ndG9wJ2NsYXNzPSduYXZpZ2F0aW9uVGV4dCd3aWR0aD0nMTkuNSUnPjxhIGhyZWY9J0RlZmF1bHQuYXNweD9zZWN0aW9uWWVhcj0yJnllYXI9MjAxMic%2BMjAxMjwvYT48L3RkPjx0ZCBiZ2NvbG9yPScjZjBmMGU4J2FsaWduPSdsZWZ0JyB2YWxpZ249J3RvcCdjbGFzcz0nbmF2aWdhdGlvblRleHQnd2lkdGg9JzE5LjUlJz48YSBocmVmPSdEZWZhdWx0LmFzcHg%2Fc2VjdGlvblllYXI9MyZ5ZWFyPTIwMTEnPjIwMTE8L2E%2BPC90ZD48dGQgYmdjb2xvcj0nI2YwZjBlOCdhbGlnbj0nbGVmdCcgdmFsaWduPSd0b3AnY2xhc3M9J25hdmlnYXRpb25UZXh0J3dpZHRoPScxOS41JSc%2BPGEgaHJlZj0nRGVmYXVsdC5hc3B4P3NlY3Rpb25ZZWFyPTQmeWVhcj0yMDEwJz4yMDEwPC9hPjwvdGQ%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%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%3D%3D&__EVENTVALIDATION=%2FwEWFAKH5NrcBAKbtOHzBQKO7pzyCQKY2J3zAwLlxIrvAwK9oZrLDQKN6YqwCgLFgqFvAsSCpY4JAq2B6YkBAsSC7agLAsuCkcwDAsqClesJArOBmZ0MAq6BncQIAuXatqUOAoDbuswKAoDbnm8C59qijgkCxNrmiQFU8mZCmbVka60Kj%2BqgzpL%2Fbfuz8A%3D%3D
```

Trying to hide an url to a public document is always stupid and useless. It also breaks the navigation (for example, you can't just open it in a new tab ...).

Comment: I got that far but posting to the URL

http://www.oml.ago.state.ma.us/default.aspx with the parameters tacked on at the end as

http://www.oml.ago.state.ma.us/default.aspx?<complete parameter string> 

in wget did nothing for me. Hence the question.

Comment: That can't work, it's POST parameters, not GET, so you can't put it in the url.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [@sebcap26](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1743957/sebcap26) for pointing me in the right direction.

I guess the solution is:

```
wget http://www.oml.ago.state.ma.us/default.aspx --post-data="parameters"
```